# Get a list of all magento categories and their id's on screen when I visit a php file

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I want to create a PHP file that will return a list of all product categories from magento and their id's when I visit this file. For example, when I visit mysite.com/category.php it should show me a list of all categories and their corresponding id's. I have searched stackoverflow and every other forum out there, I have found many similar questions but there has been nothing that solves my problem. I'm not having a problem with the code itself but I'm struggling to find out where to place this code, here is the code that I want to use.

```
category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
if ($catIds){
    foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $cats[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain what file I need to place this code inside and also could you explain which folder I need to place the file inside, and also if I need to modify my code in order to get the result I desire. Many thanks

**EDIT**

This is what I have done so far. so I create a PHP file called category.php I place this file in the root of my magento folder which will be the folder with the app, skin and media directories located inside, I then included my code into the file like so

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
    if ($catIds){
        foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $cats[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
    }
}
```

I have now included the code that @mufaddal kindly included in his answer

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;
```

So my complete category.php file should look like the following

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename; 

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
    if ($catIds){
        foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $cats[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Once i have saved this file i opened my web browser and typed in the URL of my file mysite.com/category.php and I should then see a list of all categories on the screen but all i get is a blank screen can somebody explain if I'm being really stupid and doing something wrong.

Comment: Why you should see a list of categories on your screen when you are not printing anything? You are just saving some stuff into some variables! Try to var_dump your variables to see what's inside them.

Comment: Hi Hatef can you please specify how i would add this onto my previous code thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just print your variables. You can do something like this:

```
<?php $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::init();

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$catTree = $category->getTreeModel()->load();
$catIds = $catTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$cats = array();
    if ($catIds){
        foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $cats[$cat->getId()] = $cat->getName();
    } 
} 

// Optionally you can use <pre> tag for a neater print
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cats);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here is a sample code on how you can get categories and their children on different levels. You can change level 2 to any level you want but typically level 2 categories are the main categories right below the root category so that should be the way to go!

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::init();

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2);

$catIds = $category->getAllIds();

$cats = array();
$i=0;

if ($catIds){
    foreach ($catIds as $id){
        $j=0;
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        $cats[$i]["Category ID:"] = $id;
        $cats[$i]["Category Name:"] = $cat->getName();
        $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
        foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid){
            $subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
            $subcat->load($subCatid);
            $cats[$i][$j]["Subcategory ID:"] = $subCatid;
            $cats[$i][$j]["Subcategory Name:"] = $subcat->getName();
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
} 

foreach($cats as $row){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

As ugly as it seems you can get the next subcategory levels using a *foreach()* for each level. For example this one gets the Sub-subcategories:

```
if ($catIds){
  foreach ($catIds as $id){
    $j=0;
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $cat->load($id);
    $cats[$i]["Category ID:"] = $id;
    $cats[$i]["Category Name:"] = $cat->getName();
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid){
      $subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
      $subcat->load($subCatid);
      $cats[$i][$j]["Subcategory ID:"] = $subCatid;
      $cats[$i][$j]["Subcategory Name:"] = $subcat->getName();
      $_subcats = $subcat->getChildren();
      foreach(explode(',',$_subcats) as $_subCatid){
        $_subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $_subcat->load($_subCatid);
        $cats[$i][$j][$k]["Sub-subcategory ID:"] = $_subCatid;
        $cats[$i][$j][$k]["Sub-subcategory Name:"] = $_subcat->getName();
        $k++;
      }
      $j++;
    }
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks Hatef that worked a treat but i didnt realise that it would output catagories randomly, is there anyway that i could show the parent category in the output. thanks again

Comment: @Michael Hi, this is not randomly printed. You are getting the tree model and that's how it looks like! Surely you can do what you asked for using category levels. I'll post an additional code as soon as I find time. :)

Comment: @Michael you can find the new code in the edited answer. Please consider this is just the sample for giving you an idea and  you can easily extend/change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi this worked perfectly and helped me understand more about how it works, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Hi i know i the original  question was solved, but after trying this it didnt  solve my overall problem, i am using the example by hatef to get categories and their children on different levels and i wanted to implement sub_subCatid & sub_subcats like this foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid) as well as loading the subcats

Comment: @Michael you can simply add one foreach() for every subcategory level you want to get (it's not a beautiful solution for dealing with many subcats though).

Answer (score 0):

Just put file on root of your magento folder and include Mage.php file to work with magento.
Like

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot muddafal once I have tested this I will make a post to confirm that this has worked for me

Comment: so i have tried your answer and it hasnt worked for me please see my original question for extended information